# Why udf call in a dataframe select does not work?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a sample dataframe as follows:

```
val df = Seq((Seq("abc", "cde"), 19, "red, abc"), (Seq("eefg", "efa", "efb"), 192, "efg, efz efz")).toDF("names", "age", "color")
```

And a user defined function as follows which replaces "color" column in df with the string length:

```
def strLength(inputString: String): Long = inputString.size.toLong
```

I am saving the udf reference for performance as follows:

```
val strLengthUdf = udf(strLength _)
```

And when I try to process the udf while performing the select it works if I don't have any other column names:

```
val x = df.select(strLengthUdf(df("color")))

scala> x.show
+----------+
|UDF(color)|
+----------+
|         8|
|        12|
+----------+
```

But when I want to pick other columns along with the udf processed column, I get the following error:

```
scala> val x = df.select("age", strLengthUdf(df("color")))
<console>:27: error: overloaded method value select with alternatives:
  [U1, U2](c1: org.apache.spark.sql.TypedColumn[org.apache.spark.sql.Row,U1], c2: org.apache.spark.sql.TypedColumn[org.apache.spark.sql.Row,U2])org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[(U1, U2)] <and>
  (col: String,cols: String*)org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame <and>
  (cols: org.apache.spark.sql.Column*)org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame
 cannot be applied to (String, org.apache.spark.sql.Column)
       val x = df.select("age", strLengthUdf(df("color")))
                  ^
```

What am I missing here `val x = df.select("age", strLengthUdf(df("color")))`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot mix Strings and Columns in a select statement.

This will work:

```
df.select(df("age"), strLengthUdf(df("color")))
```

Comment: Could you please give more information on what is the difference between mixing of strings and columns? It would help me in building the skill set. Thanks.

Comment: Select may be called using column name Strings, e.g. `"age"` or  Columns https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.Column The API does not allow you to to mix strings and columns in the same select call. When you call a UDF you pass a Column/Columns and it returns a Column.

Comment: one more doubt. How is the udf get's evaluated? Is it like each [row][column] is passed to the udf?

Comment: The udf is applied to the specified column in each row.